# Calculus problem regarding functions

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, functions

I am so stuck in this math problem in calculus course regarding functions.

**I have an unbounded function in [a,b].**

1. I have to proof that there is a point X ∈ [a,b] that the function is unbounded in all of this points neighborhoods.
2. I have to give an example for such a function that is unbounded in (a,b) but for each point X ∈ (a,b) , there is a neighborhoods of X that the function is bounded.

   I was given a direction to use Weierstrass theorem for a sequence.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, for 1. you should take a sequence of points $x_n\in [a,b]$ with $|f(x_n)|\ge n$.

Comment: How would that help me ?

Comment: What does the Weierstrass theorem say?

Comment: It states that each bounded sequence has a convergent sub-sequence. That's the one I know. But for the sequence you have described I cannot see how it would help.

Comment: Well, it has a convergent subsequence, converging to some point $X\in [a,b]$. Proceed.

Comment: Ok. I understand. But how do you know that the sequence you've described is a bounded sequence. I think I'm missing something here...

Comment: You have to pay attention to all the information in the problem. What is the domain of our function?

Comment: I got it. Thank you a lot!!!

Comment: You're welcome! If you want to post your final solution as an answer, I'll be glad to read it and upvote you when it's right :)

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, here's a useful strategy for compact sets (such as a closed and bounded interval) - if you want to show that there is a point which obeys a certain property, you can use the bisection method.
If $f$ is unbounded in $[a,b]$, then we can split $[a,b]$ into two pieces. $f$ must be unbounded in at least one of the two pieces. We select that piece, and continue with our process. We thus get a decreasing sequence of closed bounded sets who's diameter approaches $0$. By Cantor's lemma, the intersection of all such sets comprises of a single point. Now try to think - what can you say about this point?

For the second part, you don't have to search too hard. Try to think of the simplest unbounded functions you know. I believe that the first or second example that will come to mind will be good (or if you need more specific help - feel free to ask).

Comment: The method of successive bisection is wonderful, but the OP may not be familiar with that approach. "I was given a direction to use with Weierstrass theorem for a sequence."

Comment: Yes. I have learned Cantor's lemma, and I think it is a good strategy to use in this problem. I believe that this point is what I am looking for, but how can I formalize that in a way using definitions ?

Comment: Once you have found your "special point" x using Cantor's lemma, you inspect any given neighborhood of x. f cannot be bounded in this given neighborhood, since there would be some iteration of our bisection process such that the interval that corresponds to this iteration is contained in the given neighborhood of x, which means that f is unbounded in this neighborhood. Thus f is unbounded in any neighborhood of x - as required.